# How to correctly define a MusInherit base Form class in VB.Net (2005)

Tags: vb.net, forms, derived-class

I need all the forms of my application to implement a method.
To do that, my idea is to define a MustInherit base form, with the declaration of a MustOverride method and derive all the forms from it (of course the derived forms would implement the MustOverride method:

Base form:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseForm
    Public MustOverride Sub method()
End Class
```

Derived form:

```
Public Class DerivedForm
    Inherits BaseForm

    Public Overrides Sub method()
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works, but it suffers for the annoying drawback that the DerivedForm wouldn't show anymore in the design view.

The workaround i found is to define the BaseForm as not MustInherit (of course the method becomes Overridable):

```
Public Class BaseForm
    Public Overridable Sub method()
    End Sub
End Class
```

But of course it's not the same thing...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: This is fundamental about the way the designer works, it needs to be able to create an instance of the base class to do its job.  That's how you get the WYSIWYG view in the designer.  If you declare it MustInherit then that of course can no longer work.  So don't.

Comment: @HansPassant : I don't get it. I've used `MustInherit` forms with `MustOverride` properties and they're without no problem showed in the designer.

Comment: Sure, you'll have no problem designing the base form.  Since its base class is Form, it is not abstract.

Comment: I have no problem in viewing the MusInherit Base Form in the Designer View (although I don't need too...). I cannot instead view the Derived Form (which I need to), although the Derived Form can be correctly instantiated (therefore VB can give me the WYSIWYG), in fact my application has no problem to create and show that form when i run it

Comment: Problem occurs when you try to see your derived forms if your base form is abstract. @HansPassant is correct.

Comment: The MustInherit forms are not shown when you use the context menu to add new item (don't use add a new windows form). Use Add > New Items > Inherited Form (in Windows Form tab). In the next window where you are asked to specify your base form, the MustInherit forms are not shown.

Comment: Thank you all! That's exactly what happens. I wander why. I could understand that an abstract form cannot be displayed in the designer, since it cannot be instantiated. But, if the derived class can be instantiated, where is the problem in showing me correctly in the designer? By the way, that problem occours also if I try to design a form when in the new or in the load callback there is a call to an override method. Or when there is only constructors with parameters....

Comment: It would be very useful to have a directive that allows to differentiate the code for compiling a release and for designer use, so that I could define an instantiable class as base form for the designer and an abstract one for the release/debug version. Is there anything like that?